# SQL: Removing ALL rows that have repeated values

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I've got a table with columns:

```
Acct_no, PSTL_CODE, NAME, phone
```

I'm trying to get rid of **all** rows that share the same PSTL_CODE **and** phone (i.e. dump the ones where there's his & hers accounts, and similar scenarios)

I've pulled together the following which I *think* should only return rows with a unique PSTL_CODE:

```
SELECT * FROM Sheet1
WHERE PSTL_CODE IN
(SELECT PSTL_CODE FROM SHEET1
GROUP BY PSTL_CODE HAVING COUNT(PSTL_CODE) =1)
ORDER BY phone
```

and it's *close-ish*, but it's still returning one row where there are two accounts at the same PSTL_CODE.

and I'm stuck with Access 2007, so I can't do:

```
SELECT * FROM Sheet1
EXCEPT
(SELECT PSTL_CODE FROM SHEET1
GROUP BY PSTL CODE HAVING COUNT(*) >1)
ORDER BY phone
```

in order to just scythe away the multiples.

Help!

Comment: A sample data and desire output will help a lot to understand your question.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Have you check `DISTINCT` ? http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/unique_values2007.php

Comment: I would question your logic here are you really trying to get rid of both records?  Shouldn'nt 1 remain?  AND it seems acct_No should be a driving factor for duplicates.  those living at same address may each have their own account yet share phone numbers.  Your business need is questionable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Exists`

Considering that your unique combination is `PSTL_CODE` and `phone`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sheet1 a 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   sheet1 b 
               WHERE  a.pstl_code = b.pstl_code 
                      AND a.phone = b.phone 
               HAVING Count(*) = 1) 
ORDER  BY phone
```

It is better to define a `Unique Constraint` on `PSTL_CODE` and `phone` columns which helps you to avoid duplicate records in table

Comment: Fantastic, output looks spot-on!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the business logic correctly you are attempting to eliminate couples living together from the query. you are grouping by phone also which seems to be causing the error. Is there a logical business reason for two people to live in the same place but have different phone numbers. eg mobile phones?

Comment: I though ORDER BY just sorted the output, but didn't actually do anything to the data?  One of the things I'm doing with the data is looking for people who hold multiple accounts, but haven't updated the address details for every account when they move house.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to generate a set of unique phone, postal codes that are duplicates and then LEFT join your base set to the generated set where the postal_Code is null.

```
Select *
FROM SHEET1 A
LEFT JOIN (
  Select count(*) as cnt pstl_Code, phone
  From sheet1
  group by pstl_Code, phone 
  having count(*) > 1) B
 on A.Pstl_Code = B.Pstl_Code
and A.Phone = B.Phone
where B.pstl_Code is null and b.phone is null
```